# Angular - input

Tags: angular

I have got a data model in Angular like this:

`

```
export interface Task {
  id: number;
  taskName: String;
  description: String;
  isDone: boolean;
  taskDate: Timestamp<any>;
  group: {
    id: number,
    taskGroupName: String;
  };
}
```

`

and I tried to make an input in Angular html file to create request, which will be used later with POST method for adding new Tasks. But I encountered some problems.
Default input works well with id, taskName etc. When it comes to group-object group.id and group.taskGroupName it depends error, and value is undefined.

`

```
<input ngModel="{{modelAdd.group?.id}}" name="group.id" class="form-control" id="inputgroupb2" aria-describedby="title" placeholder="taskgroupId">
```

`

```
modelAdd: Partial<Task> = {};              (from ts file)
```

1. How to create input to group in this case and save group values into that model.
   I wanna get values from user, save to modelAdd and later send it as a request for backened.
2. Additionalny I want to add that if I tried to read data in this way, it works fine:
   So why, i cannot write it in the same way?

`

```
<div *ngFor="let task of tasks">
  <div>{{task.id}} {{task.taskName}} {{task.taskDate}} {{task.isDone}}  {{task.group.id}} {{task.group.taskGroupName}}</div>
</div>
```

`

Thank you for some help!

Answer (score 0):

How are you building the form?
What I usually do for nested forms is add the nested peice after making the original form.  My example is below.

###### Setting Up Form

```js
this.myform = this.fb.group({
  email: ['', Validators.required, Validators.email],
  phones: this.fb.array([])
})
```

###### Adding nested form

```js
addPhone() {
  const phone = this.fb.group({
  area: [],
  prefix: [],
  line: []
})
this.phoneForms.push(phone);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help. But my form is basic and looks like this:

```js
<!--  MODAL WINDOW ADD-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <form #addForm="ngForm">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit task group with Id: <b>{{modelAdd.id}}</b></h5>
            <div class="form-group">
<!--              <label for="inputTaskName2"></label>-->
              <input type="text" ngModel="{{modelAdd.taskName}}" name="taskName" class="form-control" id="inputTaskName2" aria-describedby="title" placeholder="Task name">
<!--              <input type="text" ngModel="{{modelAdd.taskDate}}" name="taskDate" class="form-control" id="inputTaskDate2" aria-describedby="title" placeholder="Task date">-->
              <input ngModel="{{modelAdd.group?.id}}" name="group.id" class="form-control" id="inputgroupb2" aria-describedby="title" placeholder="taskgroupId">
<!--              <input type="text" ngModel="{{modelAdd.group?.taskGroupName}}" name="taskGroupName" class="form-control" id="inputgroupa2" aria-describedby="title" placeholder="taskGroupName">-->
<!--              <input type="text" ngModel="{{modelAdd.description}}" name="description" class="form-control" id="inputTaskdescription2" aria-describedby="title" placeholder="Task description">-->
<!--              <input class="form-control" name="id" ngModel="{{modelAdd.id}}" id="id" [defaultValue]="modelAdd.id" type="hidden">-->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" id="" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
              <button (click)="onAddTask(addForm.value)" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>

            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I tried to save values to **modelAdd: Partial = {};**  which is based on data model from first message. Is it possible to do it this way?
I can't understand why I can read data and show it on screen using
{{ <div *ngFor="let task of tasks">
{{task.group.id}} {{task.group.taskGroupName}}}}, but I cant write it to variable/object same way.

Comment: This is not an answer it's a new question